# Understanding apps script api calls?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This script works. It has user id 4 which I am adding their email address to check the google admin API. The resolved `column[10]` is where managers approve requests. Because some of these usernames are not correctly entered, I was looking for a way to check if they were actually correct user ids. Both `.setValue()` lines work under try and catch, they also error on same users. I am trying to understand where the actual validation is happening. I guess I am trying to figure how the script knows to check the primary email address? Hope that makes sense.

```
function getNames() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
    var data = values[i];
    var resolved = data[10];
        
    if(resolved === ""){

      try{
        
        var email = sheet.getRange(1+i,4).getValues() + '@buisness.com'
        var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);
        var name  = user.name.fullName;
        
        sheet.getRange(1+i, 5).setValue('Yes this is an employee');//How does this work?
        //sheet.getRange(1+i, 5).setValue(name);//This works which I expect
        }
                   
      catch(errors){
        sheet.getRange(1+i,5).setValue(errors);              
      }      
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation happens through the `AdminDirectory.Users.get()` function with the help of the `try and catch` statements.

### Admin SDK Directory Service/Get User

This API function gets a user by their email address. If the email address exists, all their data will be logged as a JSON string. Otherwise, it will return an error.

### Try and Catch

The `try` and `catch` statements belong under JavaScript Errors. The `try` statement will run a code block that you place in it. If it encounters any error, it will trigger the `catch` statement (which usually displays the error messages.

### Your Code

Your code checks for the validity of the email address with the use of the AdminDirectory.Users.get() function inside the `try` statement. If the function fails, it returns an error which triggers the `catch` statement (which usually displays the error messages).

### References:

- [Admin SDK Directory Service/Get User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user)
- [JavaScript Errors](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: If you have other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. [how to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)